convert sql function to c# logic method
So, basically I have a requirment of passing the datetime and getting the org specific date and time.
below Sql function is working perfectly fine.
It's working even if i call the sql function from c#.
But I want to implement the same logic in c#. I want to get rid of the sql function and directly implement the logic in c# with inline queries.
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnGetConvertDateTimeWithTimeZoneOffset]    
(    
        @OrganizationID     INT,      
        @LocationID         INT,      
        @Date               DATETIME  
)    
RETURNS DATETIME    
AS       
BEGIN    
    
 DECLARE @TimeOffset            INT = 0, 
         @ConvertedDateTime     DATETIME ,       
         @DayLightSavingHour    INT = 60,
         @IsDayLight            CHAR(1) = 'N'
 SELECT @ConvertedDateTime = @Date    

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Organization_TimeZone WHERE OrganizationID = @OrganizationID AND LocationId = @LocationID AND @LocationID > 0)          
   BEGIN          
    SELECT @LocationID = 0          
   END    
SELECT  @TimeOffset = ISNULL(TimeOffsetValue,0), @IsDayLight = ISNULL(IsDayLight,'N')
            FROM dbo.Organization_TimeZone WITH (NOLOCK)             
                WHERE OrganizationID = @OrganizationID            
                    AND (ISNULL(LocationId,0) = @LocationID)            
                    AND IsActive = 'Y'
          
 IF(@TimeOffset <> 0)      
  BEGIN      
  SELECT @TimeOffset = 
         CASE WHEN  @IsDayLight = 'Y' AND @TimeOffset > 0
              THEN  @TimeOffset - @DayLightSavingHour
              WHEN  @IsDayLight = 'Y' AND @TimeOffset < 0
              THEN  @TimeOffset + @DayLightSavingHour
         ELSE  @TimeOffset
         END
   SELECT @ConvertedDateTime =  DATEADD(MINUTE,@TimeOffset,@Date)      
  END      
    


RETURN @ConvertedDateTime      
END  

this is the sql function which is called by c#.
it is working fine now.
but when I implement the same logic through c#. its not working. why?
here is my sample code which i got from chatgpt:
using System;

using System.Data.SqlClient;

public class TimeZoneConversion
{
    public static DateTime ConvertDateTimeWithTimeZoneOffset(int organizationId, int locationId, DateTime inputDate)
    {
        // Initialize necessary variables
        int timeOffset = 0;              
        DateTime convertedDateTime = inputDate; 
        int dayLightSavingHour = 60;     
        char isDayLight = 'N';          

        bool hasLocation = CheckIfLocationExists(organizationId, locationId);

        if (!hasLocation)
        {
            locationId = 0;
        }

        GetTimeZoneAndDaylightSavingInfo(organizationId, locationId, ref timeOffset, ref isDayLight);

        if (timeOffset != 0)
        {
            if (isDayLight == 'Y')
            {
                timeOffset = AdjustForDaylightSaving(timeOffset, dayLightSavingHour);
            }

            convertedDateTime = convertedDateTime.AddMinutes(timeOffset);
        }

        return convertedDateTime;
    }

    private static void GetTimeZoneAndDaylightSavingInfo(int organizationId, int locationId, ref int timeOffset, ref char isDayLight)
    {
        string connectionString = "your_connection_string_here"; // Update with your actual DB connection string
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            string query = @"
                SELECT TimeOffsetValue, IsDayLight
                FROM dbo.Organization_TimeZone
                WHERE OrganizationID = @OrganizationID
                AND (ISNULL(LocationId, 0) = @LocationID)
                AND IsActive = 'Y'";

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrganizationID", organizationId);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LocationID", locationId);

                connection.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (reader.Read())
                    {
                        timeOffset = reader.IsDBNull(0) ? 0 : reader.GetInt32(0); // Default to 0 if null
                        isDayLight = reader.IsDBNull(1) ? 'N' : reader.GetString(1)[0]; // Default to 'N' if null
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        timeOffset = 0;
                        isDayLight = 'N';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static int AdjustForDaylightSaving(int timeOffset, int dayLightSavingHour)
    {
        if (timeOffset > 0)
        {
            return timeOffset - dayLightSavingHour;
        }
        else if (timeOffset < 0)
        {
            return timeOffset + dayLightSavingHour; 
        }
        return timeOffset; 
    }

    private static bool CheckIfLocationExists(int organizationId, int locationId)
    {
        string connectionString = "your_connection_string_here"; // Update with your actual DB connection string
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            string query = @"
                SELECT 1
                FROM dbo.Organization_TimeZone
                WHERE OrganizationID = @OrganizationID
                AND LocationId = @LocationID
                AND IsActive = 'Y'";

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrganizationID", organizationId);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LocationID", locationId);

                connection.Open();
                var result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                return result != null;
            }
        }
    }
}

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            DateTime inputDate = new DateTime(2024, 11, 18, 14, 0, 0); // Example input date (UTC)
            DateTime convertedDateTime = TimeZoneConversion.ConvertDateTimeWithTimeZoneOffset(811, 1, inputDate);
            Console.WriteLine("Converted DateTime: " + convertedDateTime);
    }
    }


In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what debugging you have done.

"through c#. its not working" - that's not sufficiently describing the problem. What happens and what do expect to happen instead?

@Fildor  So when I call the sql function from c# its working working.
But I want to get rid of the sql function and directly implement the logic in c# with inline queries. I hope you got it now.

@David So when I call the sql function from c# its working working.
But I want to get rid of the sql function and directly implement the logic in c# with inline queries. I hope you got it now.

@Sherlock: " I want to get rid of the sql function and directly implement the logic in c# with inline queries." - You are encouraged to make an attempt to write your code.  If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that.  Please provide specific information about that attempt and what didn't work as expected.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Getting an exception of Specified cast is invalid

@Sherlock: This is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with using a debugger.  When you step through the code in a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?

If you have an exception, you already have a rough direction of what is wrong and you should have the exact line it happens at. That information is crucial to include in such a question. We as a community don't even know if it's that gibbiddy - garbage that throws it ...

System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'

Which dbms are you using? (The above SQL is very product specific.)

You could have been more specific in your question. Also, the code you pasted from ChatGPT shouldn't be copied directly when asking questions here. When posting a question, it's important to be as specific as possible. This platform is designed to help developers who are stuck with a specific issue, but it's not meant to provide full solutions.
I've attached a sample code below, as I've implemented a similar logic in my project. Please avoid copying and pasting it directly. Instead, adjust your logic accordingly.
          public static DateTime? GetConvertedTimeWithOffset(string connectionstring, int organizationId, DateTime date)
          {
              int timeOffset = 0;
              int? locationId = null;
              string isDayLight = "N";
              DateTime? convertedDateTime = date;
              int dayLightSavingHour = 60;
              locationId = 0;
        
              var timezoneInfo = GetTimezoneInfo(organizationId, locationId, connectionstring);
          if (timezoneInfo.HasValue)
          {
              timeOffset = timezoneInfo.Value.TimeOffset;
              isDayLight = timezoneInfo.Value.IsDayLight;
          }
    
          if (timeOffset != 0)
          {
              if (isDayLight == "Y")
              {
                  if (timeOffset > 0)
                      timeOffset -= dayLightSavingHour;
                  else if (timeOffset < 0)
                      timeOffset += dayLightSavingHour;
              }
              convertedDateTime = date.AddMinutes(timeOffset);
          }
          return convertedDateTime;
      }
    
      private static (int TimeOffset, string IsDayLight)? GetTimezoneInfo(int organizationId, int? locationId, string connectionstring)
      {
          try
          {
              using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
              {
                  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(DatabaseHelper.GetTimeZoneInfoQuery, connection);
                  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrganizationID", organizationId);
                  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LocationID", locationId ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
    
                  connection.Open();
                  using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                  {
                      if (reader.Read())
                      {
                          var timeOffsetValue = reader[0];
                          var isDayLightValue = reader[1];
    
                          int timeOffset = 0;
                          timeOffset = Convert.ToInt32(timeOffsetValue);
    
                          string isDayLight = string.Empty;
                          if (isDayLightValue != DBNull.Value)
                          {
                              isDayLight = ((string)isDayLightValue).Trim();
                          }
    
                          return (timeOffset, isDayLight);
                      }
                  }
              }
              return null;
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
              logWriter.Debug($"Error while calling GetTimezoneInfo: {ex.Message}");
              return null;
          }
      }


thank you. it worked. i had to make changes accoridng to my requirment but the logic which you provided worked.
